# Load record id to listview android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I'm new to android and I have simple problem that I cannot fix. What I want is to load listview with ID from database so that when I click on it, it will match the id in database. Here is mycode:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllContact() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts", null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_COLUMN_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllContact();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
    obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int id_in_db = position + 1
        Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
        dataBundle.putInt("cid", id_in_db);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayContact.class);
        intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
        startActivity(intent);
       }
    });
```

What I can get from onclickitem is the position of item in the list which did not match in my record in database. I can see `.setTag` method can be a solution but I don't know how to apply this in may code. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: `position` in `onItemClick` is the position of clicked item in your adapter. Hence, you can use your `arrayAdapter` to get object associated with db ID.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but how can I set in my arrayAdapter the ID so when I assign it my Listview, there is a parameter I can call in onItemClick

Comment: Can someone help on this please.

Comment: Why dont you get array list of id instead of `CONTACT_COLUMN_NAME`?

Comment: I need it to display in user interface

Comment: Why no one can answer my question? Is that really complicated?

Answer (score 0):

So you can retrieve the selected item ID this way:

```
int id_in_db = array_list.get(position).ID
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
dataBundle.putInt("cid", id_in_db);
```

and in you  DisplayContact activity load it from database or you can pass the whole item not only the ID so it will be not necessary to load it again

Comment: Ok. So what should I set to my arraylist so I can call the ID property?

Comment: For that purpose you should create model(class) like your table in DB , and instead of ArrayAdapter create custom adapter and use it with already created ArrayList<"YourModel">

Comment: If I'm going to create custom adapter, which method should I override so i can get it as parameter on onItemClick? Can you provide me sample code for this?